# Dictation is not supported in the WatchKit Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit

In Apple's release notes for 8.2 beta and Xcode 6.2 beta 4, it seems that `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:` is now supported in the simulator. However whenever I run it I get this output in the log

`Dictation is not supported in the WatchKit Simulator`

Is this documented somewhere that the text input on the simulator is still not working? Or do I need to set something up, or install something to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

No, as of iOS 8.2 beta 3 voice dictaction is not supported.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Yes, on the Apple Dev website. Search Watchkit forum for "dictation".

Comment: I need apple documentation (like a release note). Developer forums are not going to cut it. I need something I can point a customer at.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using `WKTextInputModePlain` for `allowedInputMode` gives me the error message you got, but if I'm using `WKTextInputModeAllowEmoji` instead, it works - all three input modes, including dictation. Weird but reproducible.

Xcode/Simulator 12.4, WatchOS 7.2.